# How to use Selenium on Google Colab without turning off the browser?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-colaboratory

I was trying to use Selenium on Google Colab, then an error occurred.
The error message was `"chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH."`

I googled and found a solution.
The solution was as follows:

```
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
!pip install selenium

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
```

When I removed the `--headless` option, the following error occurred.

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Is there no way to use Selenium on Google Colab without the `--headless` option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there isn't. `Google colab` is meant for `--headless`  mode.

You can not simply invoke the object of the real browser.

Comment: Thank you so much!